# Is it possible to exclude values when creating SUM in google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum

I have a profit sheet I use, and in my profits column I would like to create a SUM of the whole column whilst excluding the numbers which are negative. Anyone have any ideas of how to do this? It's a long column and manually excluding the numbers one by one would take time. The negative numbers are marked by - if that helps.

I'd imagine it needs an IF statement but i'm not too sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: SUMIF, SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT, FILTER all these formula will works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may several way to do that. One simplest way is to use `SUMIF()` function. Try-

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">0",A:A)
```

[image]